# Mongodb geonear query in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, geospatial

How can I run this mongodb command geonear in Java

> db.runCommand ({ geoNear : "mycollection", near : [
>   -121.97679901123047,37.557369232177734],   spherical : true, maxDistance : 50 / 3959 /* to radians */ ,  query : {  $or : [
>   {"myuserid" : "att"},{"_id":{$in:
>   [ObjectId("4fda8fbbe7e96e2d775595d")] }}] }    } );

I am trying this in java using Commandresult but getting error.

This is what I did so far and getting Null pointer exception although the command is printing right. I am new to java and database person.

```
BasicDBObject myCmd = new BasicDBObject(); 
myCmd.append("geoNear", "mycollection"); 
double[] loc = {-121.97679901123047,37.557369232177734}; 
myCmd.append("near", loc); 
myCmd.append("spherical", true); 
myCmd.append("maxDistance", (double)50 / 3959 ); 
System.out.println(myCmd); 
CommandResult myResults = db.command(myCmd); 
System.out.println(myResults.toString());
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The solution is to fix your code.  You're welcome.  (Hint: show us the error message for a more detailed answer.)

Comment: This is what I did so far and getting Null pointer exception although the command is printing right. I am new to java and database person. [BasicDBObject myCmd = new BasicDBObject();
myCmd.append("geoNear", "mycollection");
double[] loc = {-121.97679901123047,37.557369232177734};
myCmd.append("near", loc);
myCmd.append("spherical", true);
myCmd.append("maxDistance", (double)50 / 3959 );
System.out.println(myCmd);
CommandResult myResults = db.command(myCmd);
System.out.println(myResults.toString());]

Comment: Maybe check that myResults is not null?  Where is it throwing an exception?  What line?

Comment: The more context you provide, the easier it will be to help you. If you do not provide as much information as possible, it is very hard to think of all the things that may be wrong with your code. Please work on the question some more.

Comment: I agree, The null pointer is at CommandResult, although I can run the same on mongodb command prompt. { "geoNear" : "mycollection" , "near" : [ -121.97679901123047 , 37.557369232177734] , "spherical" : true , "maxDistance" : 0.01262945188178833}
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.xxResource.getxxx(xxxesource.java:87)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure out my  problem. Not connected to the right database. Thanks for all your help. Geo query is working fine now. Thanks.

Comment: same exception and same mistake as you did, thanks for your time in writing the mistake you did as an answer.